# Is it possible to create an enum with parameters using an .txt or .xml file?

Tags: java, xml, enums

I would like to create an enum class using a file. 
I hope to make maintenance easier.

txt example:

//name of the enum instance and devided by a '-' are the parameter values:

```
JOHN-23
ANNA-19
```

xml example:

```
<friends>
    <friend name="JOHN">
        <age>23</age>
    </friend>
    <friend name="ANNA">
        <age>19</age>
    </friend>
</friends>
```

I would like to have an enum akting like this one:

```
enum Friends {
    JOHN(23),
    ANNA(19);

    private int age;

    Friends(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to do the creation of the enum class? At compile-time or at run-time? And why does it have to be an enum class instead of a normal one?

Comment: Possible with code generation, but why?

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff first of all, because of the structure of my project it would be better to have an enum. It would be good if the enum class is created during compile-time.

Comment: Then write a Java program that reads the txt or xml, and outputs a text like your example Friends source file, and integrate a call of that program into your build tool, before it compiles your sources. It's just a bit of string manipulation as most of the result is fixed text, just the individual constants depend on your input file.

Comment: During compile time? Well, possible with java annotation processors, but this usually violates some assumptions IDEs/build systems have, most notably that it only has to recompile your enum if the corresponding java file has changed.

Comment: Do you want the code generation a manual step, or part of the build process (e.g. via maven) ?

Comment: could you give me a rough implementation or demo code? I can read code but dont know all methods needed.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn sorry, i mixed those up. Actually it doesnt realy matter (at least i think so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example how you can generate the enum with StAX in java:

```
package codegen;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class GenCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
        URL xmlFile = GenCode.class.getResource("Friends.xml");
        XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader reader = inFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlFile.openStream());

        try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter("generated/codegen/Friends.java")) {
            out.write("package codegen;\n");
            out.write("\n");
            out.write("public enum Friends {\n");

            String friendName = null;
            boolean inAge = false;
            String sep = "\t";
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                switch (reader.next()) {
                    case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                        if (reader.getLocalName().equals("friend"))
                            friendName = reader.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        if (reader.getLocalName().equals("age"))
                            inAge = true;
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
                        if (inAge) {
                            out.write(sep + friendName + "_" + reader.getText());
                            sep = ",\n\t";
                        }
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:
                        if (reader.getLocalName().equals("age"))
                            inAge = false;
                        break;
                }

            }
            out.write("\n}");
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to change some paths.

You have to compile this file, invoke it with java, which will create the Friends.java with the enum and then compile the rest.

Comment: Thy, you made my life a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it with an XSLT transformation and call out to [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) via a task in your build system.

e.g. applying this to your example XML will result in your example enum code

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:variable name="classname"><xsl:sequence select="concat(upper-case(substring(/*/local-name(),1,1)), substring(/*/local-name(), 2), ' '[not(last())])"/>  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    enum <xsl:value-of select="$classname"/>
    {<xsl:for-each select="*"><xsl:if test="position()!=1">,</xsl:if><xsl:text>
        </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>(<xsl:for-each select="*"><xsl:if test="position()!=1">, </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:for-each>)</xsl:for-each>;

<xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">        private int <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>;
</xsl:for-each><xsl:text> 
        </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$classname"/>(<xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*"><xsl:if test="position()!=1">, </xsl:if>int <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:for-each>)
        {
<xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">            this.<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> = <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>;
</xsl:for-each>        }
    }
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However,

- it would break if the XML didn't have the same number of parameters for each enum value.
- your input is encoding type names and field names as element names, whereas it's easier for metamodels to encode them as attributes
- it's easier to write transforms for explicit rather than implicit information (i.e. say that you have an int age parameter rather than just happening to have age elements whose content is a string of decimal digits)
- if you move on to anything a bit more complicated, such as generating hierarchies of classes, the queries to resolve overloads and inheritance rapidly go past simple XSLT

Comment: If its somehow possible i would preffer tho have the actual code in java and the file just for data input purpouse